# Xcode 4 Window question

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode4

Is it possible to open multiple windows in Xcode 4 if I want to have multiple files side by side ?
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can double click a file in the side panel to open it in its own window. You can also hold down command and double click a symbol within a file to open it's definition in a new window.

There is also the assistant mode where you can have two files open side by side (but in the same window).

Comment: Thanks.  So xCode 5 is not quite as terrible as it seemed at first glance.